# Package libertinus-otf and yhmath

Tags: libertinus, yhmath

The compiling the following with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
$\wideparen{ABC}$
\end{document}
```

gives the error message

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/yhmath/yhmath.sty:59: LaTeX Error:
 Command `\arrowvert' already defined.
```

What to do to prevent this?

Comment: You can use `\let\arrowvert\relax` after loading the first package and before loading the second. I don't post this as an answer because there seems to be many overlapping macros and you'd have to use this trick for each one, though.

Comment: I lot of other error messages are popping up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import `\wideparen`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}

\DeclareSymbolFont{yhlargesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{\mathord}{yhlargesymbols}{"F3}

\begin{document}

$\wideparen{ABC}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you look in `yhmath.sty`, you will find

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{yhlargesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}
```

that's the standard LaTeX way to set up a math symbol font. One needs a name and a font specification; in this case a font encoding file named `ofmyhex.fd` exists, so we need nothing else.

Next you will find the required `\DeclareMathAccent` instruction, which is the LaTeX way to define a math accent. You find several of these examples in the basic `fontmath.ltx` file, part of the LaTeX kernel.

In some other cases one needs also to specify the font declarations. A case is when you need to import symbols from `mathabx` or `fdsymbols`. For such cases, mileage may vary and some experience is needed.

Comment: can you please provide me with a link where I can learn to understand this solution?

Comment: @Ulrich There are several posts on the site that show how this works.

Comment: \@egreg, ok I will search. Your solution fixed my problem.

Comment: @Ulrich I added a few comments.

Comment: @egrep I got it.